# Recv-Q+Send-Q>write bytes

Tags: c++, c, sockets, c++11, tcp

I write a tcp server and a tcp client,the client only send data to server and print how many bytes it writed,the server only accept the connection,and then I use netstat to show the socket's Recv-Q and Send-Q,and I found that Recv-Q+send-Q > write bytes. How does it happend?

```
client code:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <errno.h>

void error(int status, int err, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, fmt);

    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);

    va_end(args);

    if (err != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "errno = %d, errmsg = %s\n", err, strerror(err));
    }

    if (status != 0)
    {
        exit(err);
    }
}

int set_address(const char *host, const char *serv, const char *protocol, sockaddr_in *addr)
{
    struct hostent *host_info;
    struct servent *serv_info;

    memset(addr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;

    if (host != NULL)
    {
        if (inet_aton(host, &addr->sin_addr) != 0)
        {
            host_info = gethostbyname(host);

            if (host_info == NULL)
            {
                error(1, h_errno, "set_address failed, gethostbyname(%s) failed, errno = %d, errmsg = %s\n", host, h_errno, hstrerror(h_errno));
            }
            else
            {
                inet_aton(host_info->h_addr_list[0], &addr->sin_addr);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    }

    if (serv != NULL)
    {
        char * end_pos;

        addr->sin_port = htons(strtol(serv, &end_pos, 10));

        if (*end_pos != '\0')
        {
            serv_info = getservbyname(serv, protocol);

            if (serv_info == NULL)
            {
                error(1, h_errno, "set_address failed, getservbyname(%s, %s) faield\n", serv, protocol);
            }
            else
            {
                addr->sin_port = serv_info->s_port;
            }
        }
    }
}

int tcp_client(const char *host, const char *serv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int fd;
    const int on = 1;

    set_address(host, serv, "tcp", &server);

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        error(1, errno, "create socket failed\n");
    }

    if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) != 0)
    {
        error(1, errno, "connect to server failed\n");
    }

    return fd;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("usage: %s <host> <port>\n", basename(argv[0]));
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[1024];
    int fd;
    int total_write_bytes = 0, cur_write_bytes = 0;

    fd = tcp_client(argv[1], argv[2]);

    while (true)
    {
        cur_write_bytes = write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if (cur_write_bytes <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        total_write_bytes += cur_write_bytes;
        printf("total_write_bytes = %d, curr_write_bytes = %d\n", total_write_bytes, cur_write_bytes);
    }

    return 0;
}

server code:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <errno.h>

void error(int status, int err, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, fmt);

    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);

    va_end(args);

    if (err != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "errno = %d, errmsg = %s\n", err, strerror(err));
    }

    if (status != 0)
    {
        exit(err);
    }
}

int set_address(const char *host, const char *serv, const char *protocol, sockaddr_in *addr)
{
    struct hostent *host_info;
    struct servent *serv_info;

    memset(addr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;

    if (host != NULL)
    {
        if (inet_aton(host, &addr->sin_addr) != 0)
        {
            host_info = gethostbyname(host);

            if (host_info == NULL)
            {
                error(1, h_errno, "set_address failed, gethostbyname(%s) failed, errno = %d, errmsg = %s\n", host, h_errno, hstrerror(h_errno));
            }
            else
            {
                inet_aton(host_info->h_addr_list[0], &addr->sin_addr);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    }

    if (serv != NULL)
    {
        char * end_pos;

        addr->sin_port = htons(strtol(serv, &end_pos, 10));

        if (*end_pos != '\0')
        {
            serv_info = getservbyname(serv, protocol);

            if (serv_info == NULL)
            {
                error(1, h_errno, "set_address failed, getservbyname(%s, %s) faield\n", serv, protocol);
            }
            else
            {
                addr->sin_port = serv_info->s_port;
            }
        }
    }
}

int tcp_server(const char *host, const char *serv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in local;
    int fd;
    const int on = 1;

    set_address(host, serv, "tcp", &local);

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        error(1, errno, "create socket failed");
    }

    if (bind(fd, (sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local)) != 0)
    {
        error(1, errno, "bind to port %s:%s failed\n", host, serv);
    }

    if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on)) != 0)
    {
        error(1, errno, "set SO_REUSEADDR failed\n");
    }

    if (listen(fd, 100) != 0)
    {
        error(1, errno, "listen on %s:%s failed\n", host, serv);
    }

    return fd;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("usage: %s <host> <port>\n", basename(argv[0]));
        exit(1);
    }

    int listen_fd, fd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t len;

    listen_fd = tcp_server(argv[1], argv[2]);

    fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &len);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        error(1, errno, "accept an connection failed\n");
    }

    while (true)
    {
        sleep(5);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this is the resulte:

standard output result:
[standard output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MQWL.png)

netstat result:
[netstat result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCsLo.png)

tcpdump result:

> 14:17:16.633105 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: S 4282375064:4282375064(0) win 32767 
>   14:17:16.633106 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: S 4268411460:4268411460(0) ack 4282375065 win 32767 
>   14:17:16.633115 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: . ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633127 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 1:1025(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633130 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 1025 win 8704
>   14:17:16.633156 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 1025:2049(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633159 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 2049 win 8704
>   14:17:16.633167 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 2049:3073(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633169 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 3073 win 8704
>   14:17:16.633176 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 3073:4097(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633179 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 4097 win 8704
>   14:17:16.633185 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 4097:5121(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633188 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 5121 win 8704
>   14:17:16.633195 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 5121:6145(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633198 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 6145 win 8704
>   14:17:16.633204 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 6145:7169(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633206 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 7169 win 8704
>   14:17:16.633213 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 7169:8193(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633215 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 8193 win 8704
>   14:17:16.633222 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 8193:9217(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633224 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 9217 win 8704
>   14:17:16.633230 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 9217:10241(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633233 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 10241 win 8704
>   14:17:16.633239 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 10241:11265(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633242 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 11265 win 8448
>   14:17:16.633249 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 11265:12289(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633251 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 12289 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633258 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 12289:13313(1024) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.633261 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 13313 win 7936
>   14:17:16.633269 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 14337 win 7680
>   14:17:16.671777 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 31757 win 3325
>   14:17:16.879921 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: P 31757:45057(13300) ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:16.959771 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 45057 win 0
>   14:17:17.175771 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: . ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:17.175786 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 45057 win 0
>   14:17:17.607770 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: . ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:17.607782 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 45057 win 0
>   14:17:18.471768 IP localhost.54393 > localhost.personal-agent: . ack 1 win 8192
>   14:17:18.471775 IP localhost.personal-agent > localhost.54393: . ack 45057 win 0

Answer (score 0):

Bytes that have been received but for which the acknowledge has not been received by the sender are in both the send queue and the receive queue. They remain in the send queue because until they are acknowledged, the sender must be ready to re-send them. They remain in the receive queue until the application calls a receive function and takes them out of the queue.

Comment: I post the tcpdump result，all sended message has been acknowledged